# Passing new Array instead of array literal to useState shows empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**This is small issue but strange!**

```
let checkedlistarr = new Array();
for (var i in items){  //items size is 30
    checkedlistarr.push(i)
 }
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(checkedlistarr);
console.log(selected)
```

**It returns `[]`**

but

```
checkedlistarr = ["0","1","2","3"];
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(checkedlistarr);
console.log(selected)
```

It returns `["0","1","2","3"]`

Why this happens? I tried concat function, too. but same issue.

Comment: I think your `console.log(selected)` is being executed before your for loop. Why don't you try `useEffect` hook.

Comment: What is `items`? Your code, as shown, works correctly. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: i tried the same it is working as expected https://repl.it/repls/TroubledUnripeCurrency can you include a reproducible example ?

Comment: I am getting the console of array items, can you check the console of this https://codesandbox.io/s/59419608-so-nc8zq

Comment: check you i value by console.log(i). Because everything looking good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small misunderstanding may be. I believe `items` must be empty or  does not have iterable properties.

As from docs [for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#:%7E:text=The%20for...in%20statement%20iterates%20over%20all), iterates over all enumerable properties.

**Ex:** If `items` is a number/boolean(`having not Iterable values`), `for-in` loop won't even execute.

```js
const items = 30
for(var i in items) {
  console.log("this won't run") // Because `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(items)` returns empty `{}`
}
```

If items has a Iterable properties, `for..in` loop executes properly. Means

```js
const items = new Array(30).fill(1) // fill some values or any object with values { 0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2... }
for(var i in items) {
  console.log("this will run", i) // Because `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(items)` returns empty `{0, {...}, 1: {...},2...}`
}
```

You can see [here demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-usestate-example-3dvter) with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure code doesn't have a problem.
The reason why it returns empty array is because of processing time.

```
console.log(selected);
```

This line would be processed before loop operation.

Comment: for-loop is synchronous - based on the code OP posted why do you think the `console.log` is executed first?